# If column is equal to a value, then null out another column

Tags: sql

I am trying to set my query to do the following: when the HWTYPE column is equal to 'Computer', I want my username column to be nulled out if it has a value. How would I achieve this? This is what I have, but it's not working:

```
 case when HWTYPE = 'COMPUTER' 
                         THEN USRNAME = ' '
                         end AS NULLTEST,
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```
select (case when HWTYPE <> 'COMPUTER' then usrname end) as usrname
```

This assumes that `HWTYPE` is not `NULL`.  The logic can easily be extended to handle that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `case` expression would be :

```
select (case when HWTYPE = 'COMPUTER' then null else usrname end) as NULLTEST
```